# What are written name conventions in labels?

Tags: names, surnames

I’m making a door sign for a baby’s nursery; should I stack the characters vertically? Should I include the family name? Are there any faux pas’s to be aware of when making a gift like this?

Comment: Is it a gift you want to make ?  would it be hanged on a door to indicate it is a specific baby's room? or indicate the room is a nursery?

Comment: It would hang on the door to celebrate the name of the new baby. It could also hang on the wall; it's more of a decoration than an indicator. I suppose this may be a more modern American tradition.

Answer (score 2):

> *It would hang on the door to celebrate the name of the new baby. It could also hang on the wall; it's more of a decoration than an indicator*

The key word is 'decoration'. You can consider it a hand crafted art. The shape of the sign should be fun and artistic (e.g. you can make it shaped like panda, star, duckling, bunny or anything you consider meaningful ). It can also be colorful. The same goes to the font you use.

Horizontal or vertical are both fine, the characters don't even have to be the same size or line up straight, but the label itself should has little thickness to make it feel substantial

Use just the baby's first name would make it more casual and relax. Using full name would make it more formal.

Answer (score 0):

- Both horizontal and vertical are fine. Vertical would look fancier.
- Definitely include the family name. It’s an integral part of Eastern names.
- Don’t write the name in red. Seriously, don’t write the name in red lettering. For people who are superstitious enough writing a name is red is tantamount to sending them off to their death.

Stylistically I like white lettering on a black background but now I’m promulgating my own fashion-sense.